# How does the compiler know how to correctly handle bitfields when reading binary data from a file in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C by writing a postgres clone and struggling to understand how the compiler handles bitfields.

Specifically, my question surrounds the bitfields in postgres' line pointer struct:

```
typedef struct ItemIdData {
  unsigned  lp_off:15,   /* offset to tuple (from start of page) */
        lp_flags:2,  /* state of line pointer, see below */
        lp_len:15;   /* byte length of tuple */
} ItemIdData;
```

In my clone, I'm able to set these fields to correct values and write them to disk, but I don't understand how the compiler is able know which of the 15 bits are relevant when converting to an integer type. Here's a full example showing what I'm doing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct ItemIdData {
  unsigned  lp_off:15,   /* offset to tuple (from start of page) */
        lp_flags:2,  /* state of line pointer, see below */
        lp_len:15;   /* byte length of tuple */
} ItemIdData;

int main() {
  ItemIdData* lp = malloc(sizeof(ItemIdData));

  lp->lp_off = 205;
  lp->lp_len = 51;

  int fd = open("line_pointer.data",
                O_RDWR |    // Read/Write mode
                  O_CREAT,  // Create file if it doesn't exist
                S_IWUSR |   // User write permission
                  S_IRUSR   // User read permission
  );

  write(fd, lp, 4);

  close(fd);
  free(lp);

  ItemIdData* lp2 = malloc(sizeof(ItemIdData));

  int fd2 = open("line_pointer.data",
                O_RDWR |    // Read/Write mode
                  O_CREAT,  // Create file if it doesn't exist
                S_IWUSR |   // User write permission
                  S_IRUSR   // User read permission
  );

  read(fd2, lp2, 4);

  printf("lp_off: %d\n", lp2->lp_off);
  printf("lp_len: %d\n", lp2->lp_len);

  close(fd2);
  free(lp2);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiling and running the program, I get:

```
$ gcc -o lp main.c && ./lp
lp_off: 205
lp_len: 51
```

Using `xxd -b`, I inspected the binary contents of the data file and see these four bytes:

```
11001101 00000000 01100110 00000000
```

`lp_off` is the first 15 bits: `11001101 0000000`, which somehow correctly converts to 205 in decimal

`lp_len` is the last 15 bits:  `1100110 00000000`, which somehow correctly converts to 51 in decimal

This is what I'm failing to to understand: how does the compiler know that the trailing 0-bits are not part of the value when converting to an int in the print statements above?

I'm coding this on Ubuntu-20.04 running inside WSL on a Windows 10 machine, if that matters.

Comment: Bitfields is one of the things that isn't well-defined in the C specification. Things like endianness, and even order of fields withing a "word", are implementation defined. So saving a bitfield to a binary file and loading it later might work, or it might not. Generally speaking, these days there's rarely any need to use binary files. Use simple text-based files instead.

Comment: Consider this question first. How does the compiler know which bits of a `float` are the mantissa, which ones are the exponent, and which one is the sign? Now explain what in your opinion prevents it from knowing the exact same thing about your `struct`.

Comment: "How does the compiler know how to correctly handle bitfields"  It doesn't. All of this is non-portable.

Comment: @Lundin Point taken about it being non-portable. However, is the behavior predictable if this code is compiled and run on the same machine, and is only reading files which it wrote itself? I ask because postgres is obviously using bitfields, and postgres is very portable. The source code is anyways - data files are not portable.

Comment: It's strictly speaking not portable to another compiler on the same machine. However if you stick to gcc and clang, chances are that they have the same behavior for little endian 32 bit `int` machines. It's "trial and error" portability... maybe it will work, no guarantees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit field allocates 15 bits for `lp_off` in which 205 is stored and `lp_len` in which 51 is stored. 205 in binary is 11001101. The extra 0 bits you are seeing are just the higher order bits, not set because the stored value is not big enough.

Given that you are on a little endian machine, the first 8 least significant bits are in the first byte, and the remaining 7 are in the next byte. If you try storing 32767 in the `lp_off`, you will see all 1 bits for the first 15 bits.

Comment: None of this is guaranteed by the C standard however, including bit order, byte order, alignment, padding bits/bytes etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

The 32 bits in the struct are stored in little endian as user16217248 says, but it is not true that the first 15 bits in the file will be all ones if offset stores 32767.

Since the struct is 15 bits + 2 bits + 15 bits it may be defined logically like this:

[image: struct]

Where o is offset, f is flag, and l is len.
But since it is little endian it will be stored in memory and written to disk like this:

[image: struct]

so for instance writing 32767 to offset and length with 0 to flag will yeild:

11111111 01111111 11111110 11111111

because the least significant bit of the flag is stored first in the byte (2nd byte of struct) containing it, and the most significant bit of the flag is stored last in the byte (3rd byte of struct) containing it.

So, if flag = 1 it would have been:

11111111 11111111 11111110 11111111

and flag = 2,

11111111 01111111 11111111 11111111